Why do I get an error after trying to invoke SageMaker through Lambda?
I am trying to invoke SageMaker through Lambda, but I am getting an error.
Here is the error:
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary and could not load the entire response body. See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/jira-endpoint in account xxxx for more information.",
  "errorType": "ModelError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 19, in lambda_handler\n    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 565, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 1021, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}

The model endpoint is from a prebuilt model-uri.
Here is my Lambda code:
import os, io, boto3, json, csv, base64


ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    project = event['project']
    # project = base64.b64decode(event['project'])
    # timeline = base64.b64decode(event['timeline'])
    
    # payload = """{}.
    #     Given the project description above, sugges a project tasklist to achieve the project goals.
    #     The project timeline is {} weeks.
    # """.format(project, timeline)

        
    payload = project
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                       Body=project, ContentType="text/csv")
                                     
                                     

    result = json.loads(response["Body"].read().decode())
    print(result)
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": { "content-type": "application/json"},
        "body":  result
    }

Also, I am not certain in what format the SageMaker endpoint expects to receive the JSON data.
Thank you for your help!

Thank you everyone for your help, I have been able to resolve this issue.

In order to investigate what caused the "ModelError", you need to check the logs from the model container. Logs from endpoints are emit to "/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/[EndpointName]". Please check if you see more specific error message there.
For more information where SageMaker emits logs, see this document page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/logging-cloudwatch.html

Hello, thank you for your help. I have been able to resolve this. Thank you.
